# What's the best way to list a non-ruby dependency of a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependency-management

I am writing a ruby gem that I would like to use an open source program distributed as python.  I don't have the time to port the python program to ruby, and I want to manage the external dependency as automatically as possible.

I'm thinking of using the Gem.pre_install hook to automatically easy_install the python package I'm interested in.

http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/Gem.html#method-c-pre_install

I'd appreciate suggestions of better ways, or support of pre_install, if it's the accepted practice.

Comment: Pester the Ruby community to cooperate better with Linux distributions' packaging systems.  Becuase apt-get and yum can handle this sort of thing a lot better than rubygems can.

Comment: @Ken: You're of the opinion that it's the Ruby community being unwilling to cooperate with Linux distributions, rather than vice versa?

Comment: @Andrew: I think that adding a particular feature to RubyGems whereby a distribution package can tell RubyGems "hey! I provide X version of Y gem" (by dropping a file in `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/equivs`) would go a long way towards integrating RubyGems with the packaing system.

Answer (score 1):

Quite an old question, but worth a reply. Sorry, I haven't been checking stackoverflow for babushka-related questions :)

If the python package is available as a pip, then you could do something like this:

```
dep 'blah.gem' do
  requires 'something.pip'
end

dep 'something.pip'
```

Then, `babushka blah.gem` would handle the install, including installing rubygems and pip as required.

- Ben

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at Babushka for describing non-ruby dependencies.

I don't know whether installing the python package in the pre_install hook would be polite behaviour.

Comment: There's another question about Gem.post_install that indicates the hooks are run globally for all Gems after they're setup. That's really not what I want...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571422/post-install-hook-for-a-particular-gem