# How do you specify a gem's dependency on a unix program, e.g. fmt or tidy?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

How do you specify in a gem's gemspec that the gem assumes that "fmt" or "tidy" is installed on the system? These are unix tools and not Ruby gems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to list a non-ruby dependency of a gem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964257/whats-the-best-way-to-list-a-non-ruby-dependency-of-a-gem)

Comment: Pester the Ruby community to cooperate better with Linux distributions' packaging systems. Becuase apt-get and yum can handle this sort of thing a lot better than rubygems can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another place where rubygems just lacks...

A few workarounds:

put a message about it in the post_install message

check for it at runtime

check for it at install time by using a fake mkrf_conf.rb http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/RubyGems#How_to_install_different_versions_of_gems_depending_on_which_version_of_ruby_the_installee_is_using

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`requirements`](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#requirements) attribute. It doesn't actually enforce the dependency, but it looks like the right place to put the information.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in the README and hope people read it. ;)